# Error between truncated randomized SVD and truncated SVD

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank, svd, random-matrices

I am studying randomized SVD. However, many works give the error of randomized SVD like
$$
\|A-QQ^TA\|_F\leq (1+\epsilon)\|A-A_k\|_F,\text{ and}\quad \|A-QQ^TA\|_2\leq (1+\epsilon)\|A-A_k\|_2
$$
where $A_k$ is the best rank $k$ approximation of $A$.

Intuitively, $\|A_k-(QQ^TA)_k\|_F$ and $\|A_k-(QQ^TA)_k\|_2$ should approach $0$ when $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ where $(QQ^TA)_k$ is the best rank $k$ approximation of $QQ^TA$. Is this correct if the low rank approximation of $A$ is unique?